# How to set/update clicked item in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Could you please tell me how to how to set/update a clicked item in React.js?.
I want the value of the clicked element to change to "test". How can I setup such event handler to do this?

Here is [my code](http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/wGbQzV?editors=1010)

On item click I am trying to update the item like that

```
   btnClick(obj) {
        obj.hse = 'test';
        console.log(obj);
        // this.setState({
        //     data: [obj]
        // });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `data` object is an array, I think the easiest way to implement this is to send your `btnClick()` function the `id` of the element that was clicked, update that value, and then save the new state.

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpyQYN?editors=1010)

Like so:

```
this.state.data.map((item, i) => {
  return <li onClick = {
    this.btnClick.bind(this, i)
  > {
     item.hse
  } < /li>;
})
```

By changing `map(item) => {` to `map(item, i) => {` you make use of the `index` parameter of the [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. This `i` variable is then used when binding the `btnClick` function.

```
btnClick(id) {
    let temp = this.state.data.slice();
    temp[id].hse = 'test';
    this.setState({
      data: temp
    });
}
```

Here, the `id` is the index of the item clicked. Start off by creating a shallow copy of the `this.state.data` and put it into a local `temp` variable. Then, change the `hse` property of `temp[id]`. Finally, update the `data` state with the local variable.

*edit: fixed broken codepen link*